# I need to use java 8 filter to filter my list of custom objects in efficient manner

Tags: java, java-8

The code below is in java 6. How to code it in java 8 using streams and functional capabilities ?

```
List<FileTransAuditInfo> workRequestFileTransAuditListforSubmission = new ArrayList<FileTransAuditInfo>();

for(FileTransAuditInfo fileTransAuditInfo : workRequestFileTransAuditList) {
    if (fileTransAuditInfo.getFileEventType().equalsIgnoreCase(type1) ||
        fileTransAuditInfo.getFileEventType().equalsIgnoreCase(type2)) {
            workRequestFileTransAuditListforSubmission.add(fileTransAuditInfo);
    }
}

return workRequestFileTransAuditListforSubmission;
```

Comment: So what seems to be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of your code in Java 8 would be :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<FileTransAuditInfo> workRequestFileTransAuditList = new ArrayList<>();

    final String type1 = "type 1";
    final String type2 = "type 2";

    List<FileTransAuditInfo> workRequestFileTransAuditListforSubmission = workRequestFileTransAuditList.stream()
            .filter(file -> file.getFileEventType().equalsIgnoreCase(type1) || file.getFileEventType().equalsIgnoreCase(type2)) 
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Check here how to use [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) in Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

First `.stream()` the `List`, then use [`Stream#filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) and finally `collect` to a new `List`.

You can reduce how repetitive your filter testing is by using a helper function.

```
Function<String,Predicate<FileTransAuditInfo>> eventTypeIs =
    type -> file -> file.getFileEventType().equalsIgnoreCase(type);

return workRequestFileTransAuditList
    .stream()
    .filter(eventTypeIs.apply(type1).or(eventTypeIs.apply(type2)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: nice use of `or` method from `Predicate<T>`